# @font-face files does not load offline

Tags: css, font-face

I'm having trouble using `@font-face` with fonts located on my machine. My files aren't on a server yet. I'm trying to preview them offline, but they aren't loading.

Here is the code from the css file:

```
@font-face{
   font-family:"chunk";
   src: url('file:///C:/...Fonts/Chunkfive.otf');
}
div{
   font-family:"chunk";
}
```

Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that would work. Have you tried using a relative path to the html rather than a file path.

Comment: Security settings may well be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Include them in your site folder, and reference them as you do with images.

Answer (score 0):

@pvenkat; if your `font folder & css in same folder` then just write this `Fonts/Chunkfive.otf` in your url path & if your css folder some other folder like in `stylesheet folder` then write `../Fonts/Chunkfive.otf` in your path may be that's work for you.